# Angularjs 1.3.5 ng-click not calling function in controller from route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-route

I've checked similar answers and tried modify the Plunkers which work, but doing something similar fails in my project (could be due to their example using AngularJS 1.1.0).

I've gone through the tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial, but still quite new to AngularJS.

For my project, I'm using AngualarJS version 1.3.9 and the following modules:

- ngResource
- ngRoute

I'm having problems with ng-click.

Here is my routing setup:

```
app.config([
        "$routeProvider", 
        function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.

            when("/calendar",{
                templateUrl:"templates/test.php",
                controller: 'TestController',
            }).
        ...
    }
]);
```

My test.php:

```
<button data-ng-click="test2()">Thing</button>
{{test}}
```

Here is my controller:

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller("TestController", 
    ["$scope", 
    function($scope){
        $scope.test = "Hello";

        $scope.test2 = function(){
            alert("okay");
        };
    }
]);
```

When I load the page, "Hello" shows up but pressing the button does nothing (no errors in console and it's not inside a form).

I've seen some examples using data-ng-click but that doesn't work either. 
The following example from the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick) does work, so I think my problem could be a scope issue:

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
count: {{ count }}
```

Can anyone confirm and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

There wasn't any console errors about injections and routing was working fine, but I should have included my app.js for completeness (file also contained my routing setup, for the time being but not a big deal yet):

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module(
    // Name of app, linked to ng-app
    'testApp', 
    // Dependencies
    [
     'ngRoute',             // Use the routing service
     'ngResource',
    ]
); 

//The routing part goes here 

})();
```

Comment: should work, maybe you've disabled alerts?

Comment: Show your app.js in which you have bootstrapped the angular.Are you loading angular javascript file?

Comment: @YangLi, I've tried loading the test site and it appears to work! So, the alerts might have been disabled.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani - Yes, the angular file is loaded from my index.php in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is showing "Hello", then your route is working and so your controller. The problem may be is with the alert. Modify your

```
$scope.test2 = function(){
        alert("okay");
    };
```

to

```
$scope.test2 = function(){
        $scope.test = "World";
    };
```

If the page updates the value, then the problem is with your browser disabling alerts.

Comment: After testing on another computer, the alerts seem to work! The browser on my original computer may have disabled the alerts. I did do a shift + F5, but perhaps I need to clear the cache manually. Might have happened when checking 'prevent additional dialogs' when testing a ng-repeat with alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject ngRoute:

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', ['ngRoute']);
```

You also need to place ng-view element in your app html:

working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IDo6ZRX4a0l5Piz6uzbA

note: double click the button to show your alert

Comment: I've updated to show my app.js which did inject ngRoute and my index.php did have ng-view in a div tag. Thanks for creating the plunker though.